# How can I link an object on save in django to an existing one if there is a matching value between them?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I'm using `Django` and `DRF` to reconcile two lists of data (promises to pay, and payments). When uploading new payments, if the payment transaction ID shares the same ID as a promise to pay, I want to link them by saving the corresponding promise in the payment's foreign key field.

**I have two models:**

```
class Promise(models.Model):
     transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     amount_promised = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
     created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Payment(models.Model):
    promise = models.OneToOneField(Promise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount_paid = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**and two views:**

```
class PromiseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsCreatorOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Promise.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PromiseSerializer

class PaymentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsCreatorOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Payment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PaymentSerializer
```

My understanding is this requires a custom save method, but I'm not certain if the magic should be happening in views or models. Either way, the logic should be something like:

- *Loop through promises...if the new payment.transaction_id = a promise.transaction_id, break and link the two together by saving the promise.pk to the promise foreign key in the newly created payment object.*

Here are my updated thoughts on a potential solution:

```
class PaymentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsCreatorOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Payment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PaymentSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        queryset = Promise.objects.filter(transaction_id=self.transaction_id)
        if queryset.exists():
            return queryset.pk
        serializer.save(queryset.pk=self.promise)
```

Comment: Are the promises and payments done in a single turn (single upload) or promises are already in the database and you are matching them now with payments?

Comment: The promises are already saved in the database, so it's more about matching the payments to the existing promises.

Comment: Why you don't do this while processing payments in the view? If you are sure that IDs are the same, simply do lookup in the Promise and if found add that as a foreign key to Payments.

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic I updated the solution in the question. Can you help me improve it?

Comment: And what happens if you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think using django.db.models.signals.post_save can be a option here.